# Windows 7 32-bit Program Files path in a Batch file Issue

Tags: windows, path, batch-file

I have batch file that I am inheriting and I cannot get to work in a 64bit Windows 7 environment. The batch file makes a call to a java script, and passes two variables in it. The old on looked like this:

```
 C:\Progra~1\salesf~1.com\ApexDa~2.0\bin\process.bat     C:\Progra~1\*PATH*     *VARIABLE*
```

This was run onm 32bit XP which has just the one program files. I have tried every way I can think of to change the being of the the path to Program fiels x86. I  have tried SET PATH, SET ExecPath, %ProgrmaFiles(x86), but they all return cannot find the path specified. I am sure the answer is easy, and I know there is a much beeter way to do this, and it will be changed, but for the moment, I need this to work. Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure dos(/short) pathnames are available on Windows 64bit?

Comment: @Christian, they are implemented as hard links in the file system driver. While it can be disabled (and should be for some cases), it still is enabled by default.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you type

```
 dir /x c:\
```

then this shows the directory listing in the 8.3 format.  `Program Files` expands to `PROGRA~1` and `Program Files (x86)` expands to `PROGRA~2`.  So I think you'll need to change the script to use `PROGRA~2`

EDIT: I agree with Mark that this isn't ideal -- it depends how much you are able to change of the legacy scripts. On a Win7 machine you should be able to use `%ProgramFiles%` and `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` (note the trailing '%').

Comment: you may want to make you code more generic and calculate this value.  e.g. something along the lines of for %x in ("%ProgramFiles(x86)%") do echo %~fsx

Comment: That is dangerous. The ~1 and ~2 do not necessarily map to `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)`.It might work on 99% of machines, but the tilde abbreviation just means "the first folder that starts with "Progra", and there is no well defined meaning to "first".

Answer (score 1):

export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/Progra~1/java/jdk1.7.0_40/

This worked for me.

Comment: That will only work in a Cygwin environment, not a batch script

Comment: .. for Batch Scripting, Use SET A=B:\X\y\Z